# Convert a full length column to one variable in a row in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to convert 1 column into 1 variable next to eachother

i.e.:

```
d <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
> d
    y
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
```

Convert this column into:

```
> d
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: The main purpose of this is to use these values as a RowSideColors in heatmap.2 depending on their value the color change in a side bar

Comment: for example `unname(unlist(d))`

Comment: You desired output isn't clear. You have a `data.frame` that contains a single vector and all you want to do is to extract that single vector? Or you want some additional manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know how are you going to use the numbers, but I think it is unnecessary to make any transformation. You can use `d$y` to get the numbers applied to any map of colors. See for example.

```
d <- data.frame(y = 1:7)
library(RColorBrewer)
mypalette<-brewer.pal(4,"Greens")
mycol <-palette()#rainbow(7) 
heatmap(matrix(1:28,ncol=4),col=mypalette[d$y[1:4]],xlab="Greens (sequential)",
      ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n",RowSideColors=mycol[d$y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the prupose of:

> 1 variable next to eachother

But there are few ways to get the desired result (again, depends on the objective). You can do either:

1. `d$y`
2. `unname(unlist(d))` #suggested by   agstudy
3. or, better yet, to convert your dataframe's column into a vector, do this:

   ```
   v <- as.vector(d[,1])
   ```
4. as string:

   ```
       args <- paste(d$y, sep=" ")
       args<-noquote(args)
   ```

now you'll have

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: What's `as.vector` for?

Comment: I agree with @DavidArenburg, `as.vector` is redundant here since `d[, 1]` without specifying `drop = FALSE` will return a vector in any case.

Comment: oh, it looks like I overlooked this comment. True - as.vector is redundant but it gives the desired result. Wasn't really sure about the OP objective here. Should you want to edit the answer the way you see fit, please do so.